# Can US expat open an HSA?

Tags: united-states, hsa

I am 60 US citizen, live in Costa Rica, receive a pension, and have a high deductible ($2500) US expat health insurance. I was wondering if I can open and use an HSA to pay my healthcare costs in CR and reduce my taxes?